# How to avoid redundancy when using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a big txt file in which there are strings. I want to apply several functions on these strings with the shortest time. I then thought of using threads.
Let's say I have these two functions:

```py
def length(string):
    print len(string)

def numberOfPoints(string):
    print string.count('.')
```

Without threads I would do:

```py
with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    samples = f.read().splitlines()

for s in samples:
    length(s)
    numberOfPoints(s)
```

My problem occurs when I want to use threads, I would do in this way:

```py
import threading

with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    samples = f.read().splitlines()

for s in samples:
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=length, args=(s,))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=numberOfPoints, args=(s,))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

But in doing so, I feel like I am missing the inner property threads provide. I want a thread that computes the length of each string in the file and an other that computes the number of points of each string in the file. In my loop, I am creating (2 * the number of strings in my file) threads. How can I load all the strings from the file without reading the file twice like this:

```py
import threading

def length(samples):
    for s in samples:
        print len(s)

def numberOfPoints(samples):
    for s in samples:
        print s.count('.')

with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    samples = f.read().splitlines()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=length, args=(samples,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=numberOfPoints, args=(samples,))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: By iterating over the list inside the `length` and `numberOfPoints` you are *not* "...reading the file twice...". Performing iteration inside a thread instead of over threads is an important optimization to reduce thread overhead.

Comment: @JamesKPolk When thread1 and thread2 are running they are both going through each string in the list, so they basically both read the same list but if time of execution is measured, we end up having a time as if we went through only one list (because thread1 & thread2 are running in the same time). Am I right when I say this, or do these two threads share the same list when they read it?

Comment: Well, now you bring up another issue which is how python actually implements threading. I'm not expert enough on python threading to answer that, but my quick look suggests that there is something called the global interpreter lock, GIL for short, which may frustrate any attempts to achieve faster throughput for CPU-bound computation, at least via threads. For I/O, it appears thread-based concurrency is not hampered by the GIL.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I had a look on GIL, but it is no fully clear to me at the moment, I'll do more research, thank you for your answers James.